Bessel Function Integral Identity
I would like to prove the following identity:

$$
\!\!\operatorname{J}_{0}\left(\sqrt{t^{2} - x^{2}}\,\right) 
= \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi/2} 
\!\!\!\!\!\!\cos\left(\,t\cos\left(\,\theta\,\right)\,\right)
\cosh\left(\,x\sin\left(\,\theta\,\right)\,\right)\, {\rm d}\theta
$$

I more or else found this result from an attempt at trying to find the Laplace inverse of the function
$$
F(x,s) = \frac{e^{-x\sqrt{s^2+1}}}{\sqrt{s^2+1}}.
$$
The result of this inversion should be
$$
F(x,t) = J_0(\sqrt{t^2-x^2}\,)\,H(t-x).
$$
This was based on a table I found after downloading this the two linked volumes of the book from this link.  You can download volume 1, and go to page 227 to find it.
https://authors.library.caltech.edu/records/mhd23-e0z22
The above integral is what you should arrive at when you take the Inversion Integral and integrate over the complex plane.  Having tested its values for x and t, it appears to be consistent with my result.  Would anyone be able to show that this is true?
I tried rewriting the integrand in the following way:
$$
\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos(t\cos(\theta)) \cosh(x\sin(\theta)) \, d\theta 
= \operatorname{Re} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos(t\cos(\theta) + ix\sin(\theta)) \, d\theta
$$
But I am not sure where to go from here, any thoughts?

Mathematica validates the inverse Laplace transform $$\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left\frac{e^{ -x \sqrt{s^2+1}}}{\sqrt{s^2+1}}\right=\left{\begin{array}{cc}
J_0\left(\sqrt{t^2-x^2}\right) & t\geq x \
0 & \text{Otherwise} \
\end{array}\right.$$ is correct.

Yeah that result is in accordance with the result in the table, I actually figured out how to get my integral result to match this, I’ll post it later, but if someone figures it out and wishes to add on, that would be great!

Oh shoot sorry, I’ll repost the link!

I posted the link where I downloaded the book from, you can look at volume 1, on page 227.

@JessieChristian. Then merge the sine and the cosine together (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Sine_and_cosine), hence the square root, and the result will match with one among numerous integral representations of the Bessel function.
